# Java vs. C Simple Performance Test

Tags: java, c, performance, printing, comparison

im running a simple loop that prints out the iterator (i) for 1.000.000 times in both java and c.

im using netbeans and visual studio respectively.

i dont care about precision but at about 40 seconds:

netbeans (java) has printed about 500.000 numbers
while windows (c) has printed about 75.000 numbers

-- why such a big difference?

im using a common intel core2duo(2.0 Ghz) pc with windows7

Comment: why dont you post your code snippets ? But, I have to say this is a very limited way to benchmark performance of a language. Since, this is just mostly IO. There is probably some buffering issue.

Comment: What compilers are you using?  What optimisation settings?  Which JVM/JDK?

Comment: See smartnut. Unless you specifically want to measure console output performance, your benchmark is so fundamentally flawed it's not even funny.

Comment: Next time I need to print the numbers from 0..1000000 I'll be sure to use Java instead of C.

Answer (score 6):

That seems wrong. Could you provide your code?

My Versions:

C version compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -o itr itr.c` with `gcc 4.5.1`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Java Version compiled as `javac Itr.java` with `javac 1.6.0_20` and JVM being:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.1) (ArchLinux-6.b20_1.9.1-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

code -

```
class Itr
{
    public static void main( String[] av )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and the times:

```
time ./itr
// Snip Output //

real    0m1.964s
user    0m0.330s
sys     0m1.477s


time java Itr
// Snip Output //

real    0m5.245s
user    0m2.337s
sys     0m3.023s
```

The test system is a Intel Core i5 M520 ( @ 2.4GHz ) running 64 bit ArchLinux.

Comment: I suspect you're measuring JVM startup time rather than the actual loop here....

Comment: mikera: I ran it a couple times before taking the submitted time. Is there any way to force the JVM to stay loaded in memory? I don't doubt you (it seems a bit higher than it should be, but that's what I got.)

Comment: Those test timings include the startup of the JVM, which is known to be costly by comparison with the C runtime. It also doesn't matter a great deal in most situations where performance is actually critical, as most usage of Java only starts processes occasionally.

Comment: @Reese Moore: Ouch, that's some **UB** right there, with uninitialized loop variable in C. With a million new lines, you can't really even see where it began.

Comment: Did you run the test from within NetBeans? The output to the NetBeans output window is probably a lot slower than the output in a Windows command line window.

Comment: eq: wow, didn't catch that (long day). / Fixed and updated the times

Answer (score 2):

One way to considerably speed up your example would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) 
        sb.append(i).append("\n");

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

String concatenation or output (in your case printing to standard output stream) in a loop is bad by design and not the fault of Java, you just generally want to avoid that.

It is much faster if you minimize the calls to output and use a local buffer. Also concatenating Strings is also inefficient - Java has `StringBuilder` class for that task.

Answer (score 1):

1. Without providing your code and environnement settings, your test have no value.
2. Are you sure that the NetBeans console display isn't slown down in C case, or optimized for Java output?
3. Are you sure you did run the two projects in optimized mode without debug? C debug versions often generate a lot of debug informations that clearly slow down everything if you're debugging. Anyway, any benchmark should be done with optimization AND no debug mode.

Comment: Where does he say he is using C++?

Comment: Ah yes, I assumed he might have used std::cout but it's not available in C++...